# mapping over multiple parameters - using pmap_dfr

Tags: r

This post follows on from an earlier one which has been solved. My new issue is how to correctly use `pmap`. I pass a list argument and my function.

I want to pass:

```
day = 1

month = 11

year = 2015
```

To take this a little further I want to pass the values obtained here:

```
library(lubridate)
seq.Date(from = as.Date("2015-01-01"), to = as.Date("2015-02-01"), by = "day") %>% 
  tibble::enframe(., name = "seq", value = "date") %>% 
  mutate(year = year(date),
         month = month(date),
         day = day(date))

  # A tibble: 32 x 5
     seq date        year month   day
   <int> <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <int>
 1     1 2015-01-01  2015     1     1
 2     2 2015-01-02  2015     1     2
 3     3 2015-01-03  2015     1     3
 4     4 2015-01-04  2015     1     4
 5     5 2015-01-05  2015     1     5
 6     6 2015-01-06  2015     1     6
 7     7 2015-01-07  2015     1     7
 8     8 2015-01-08  2015     1     8
 9     9 2015-01-09  2015     1     9
10    10 2015-01-10  2015     1    10
```

Function:

```
Temps <- function(day, month, year){
  month = stringr::str_pad(month, width = 2, pad = 0)
  day = stringr::str_pad(day, width = 2, pad = 0)
  url <- paste("https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/spain/madrid/historic?hd=", year, month, day, sep = "")
  temps_obtained <- url %>% 
    html_session() %>% 
    read_html() %>% 
    html_table(fill = TRUE) %>% 
    .[[2]] %>% 
    setNames(.[1,]) %>% 
    as_tibble(., .name_repair = "universal") %>% 
    dplyr::slice(., -1) %>% 
    dplyr::slice(., -n())
  return(temps_obtained)
}


purrr::pmap(list(1, 11, 2015), .f = Temps())
```

Comment: You can pass a named `list` i.e. `purrr::pmap(list(day = 1, month = 11, year = 2015), Temps)`. Unfortunately, your function is returning `No data available` `Temps(1, 11, 2015)`

Comment: ah! I promise you I at least tried this in one of my many attempts! Thanks again!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we are using `pmap`, make sure the `list` arguments are named to match the arguments of the function

```
purrr::pmap(list(day = 1, month = 11, year = 2015), Temps)
```

---

Or if we pass an unnamed `list`, then extract each components, with `..`

```
purrr::pmap(list(1, 11, 2015),  ~ Temps(day = ..1, month = ..2, year = ..3))
```